# SQL: Use STRING_AGG with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation, string-agg

I have the following PostgreSQL query: (This is a Kata at `codewars`, you can find it at the following link: https://www.codewars.com/kata/64956edc8673b3491ce5ad2c/train/sql )

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    s.id AS student_id,
    MIN(s.name) AS name,
    CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(c.course_name) = 0 THEN 'quit studying' 
      WHEN SUM(CAST(c.score < 60 AS INTEGER)) >=3
        THEN CONCAT('failed in ', STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c.course_name, '(', c.score, ')'), ', ' ORDER BY c.course_name)) 
      ELSE NULL
    END AS reason
  FROM students s
  FULL OUTER JOIN courses c
    ON c.student_id = s.id
  GROUP BY s.id
) df
WHERE reason IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY student_id
```

It works fine, but I need a little tweak, I am using `STRING_AGG` to join all rows in just one value, what I need to do is to include only rows with less then 60 `score`.

Query result right now:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: Filtering is done in the `WHERE` clause. If you want to aggregate only courses with a score above 60 you need to filter them in `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for your reply. I can't do it, because I have other conditions to be checked, those conditions need all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [filtered aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
STRING_AGG(CONCAT(...), ', ' ORDER BY c.course_name) FILTER (WHERE c.score < 60)
```

That will only aggregate over the rows that match the condition, but there won't be any other effects on your query.

Comment: In case someone has trouble finding the docs, see: [4.2.7. Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#:~:text=Section%C2%A08.16.5.-,4.2.7.%C2%A0Aggregate%20Expressions,-An%20aggregate%20expression)